# What's wrong with my vmware start script?

Tags: vmware-server

I am starting a vmware 2.x vm on a linux host.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
vmrun -T server -h https://localhost:11768/sdk -u tore -p mypass123 start "[my1] server1/server1.vmx"
```

The result when I call the script is:

```
Error: Cannot open VM: [my1] server1/server1.vmx, The virtual machine cannot be found
```

But I can start the vm from the browser ui. And in the browser ui it is configured like this:

```
Virtual Machine Configuration File: [my1] server1/server1.vmx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `localhost` with the `ipaddress` of the host.